# SQL - finding a distinct 1 to 1 relationship value in a many to many table

Tags: sql

For some context: I'm trying to find any member that has only 1 type of insurance out of 3 possible types which are either DTH, TPD or IP. Now 1 member may have 1 or 2 or all types of insurance.

Now I have 2 columns in SQL, column A has member numbers which can be duplicated if the member has multiple types of insurance. Column B has the type of insurance which obviously contains duplicates.

How do i filter my query to find members in column A that only have for example, IP type of insurance. I've tried using 'not like' and 'not in' operators to filter for the type of insurance I want however I'm still getting members that have the other types as well which i dont want.I can't even export the data to excel and check manually as the data amount is too big. I want members that have ONLY IP or ONLY DTH or ONLY TPD for example. Any ideas?

Comment: Add which flavor of RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

In general these are the members with only one record (one type of insurance):

```
SELECT 
    member,
    COUNT(member) as total
FROM Table 
GROUP BY member
HAVING COUNT(member) = 1;
```

The idea here is that if a member has one type of insurance, you see one record so count is (1) for that member, but if a member has two types of insurance, they have two records, so count is (2) for that member, and so on.

Next, to see them in more detail, since you now know the members you are interested in, just join back to the original table again using that result set:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Table A
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT 
        member,
        COUNT(member) as total
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY member
    HAVING COUNT(member) = 1
) B
ON A.member = B.member;
```

so now you can see the details (insurance types) for those members.

Now, you said "Column B has the type of insurance which obviously contains duplicates." ... this is a little unclear, but if you really mean this  then you will have to remove the duplicates, so, same as above but with more data cleaning. This would be needed, for instance, if your data has a member with one row for type DTH and two rows for type TPD, so we want to have a count for that member of (2), not (3)!

```
SELECT 
    X.member,
    COUNT(X.member) as total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT member, type FROM Table) X
GROUP BY X.member
HAVING COUNT(X.member) = 1;
```

and for the fuller version of the same:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM Table A
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT 
        X.member,
        COUNT(X.member) as total
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT member, type from Table) X
        GROUP BY X.Member
        HAVING COUNT(X.member) = 1
) B
ON A.member = B.member
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Example of the query is below: